# AngularJS delay run() method until controllers loaded

Tags: angularjs, controller, broadcast

My module run() method checks if a user is logged in, then decides which view to load.
The view slides in with a CSS animation, but as the animation is triggered (via - `classlist.add()` - I want to broadcast an event and get the controller to respond to that:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
run( function( $rootScope ) {

        $rootScope.loadView = function( view, animation ){ 
            // trigger the animation, which sends the $scope.$broadcast();
        }

        if(localStorage.loggedIn == 'false') {
            $rootScope.loadView( 'TutorialView' );
        } else {
            $rootScope.loadView(  'InterestView', 'slideUp');
        }
    }
);

myApp.controller('TutorialCtrl', ['$scope', function( $scope ){
    console.log('loaded');
    $scope.$on('TutorialViewCalled', function( event ) {
        console.log('tutorial class called');
    });         
}]);
```

In the service that does the animation I've got this code:

```
console.log('the broadcast is: ' + targetClass+'Called');
$rootScope.$broadcast( targetClass + 'Called' );
console.log('broadcast the call');
```

My console.log() outputs look like this:

```
the broadcast is: TutorialViewCalled
broadcast the call
loaded
```

So when the `loadView()` is called in `run()`, the `TutorialCtrl` hasn't yet been loaded. Any subsequent animations are fine, which I'm triggering with buttons in the view:

```
the broadcast is: InterestViewCalled
interest class called
broadcast the call
interest class loaded
```

So it looks like the `run()` method is running before my controllers are ready. Am I not using `run()` properly, I assumed it would be the last thing to actually run, waiting for everything else to be loaded first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my solution to this was to get a list of all controllers on a module, and at the end of each one broadcast a "Loaded FooCtrl" event.

I stored the controller name in an array in the rootScope, then did a `sort()` and `join()` and checked the string matched with the controllers gathered from a method similar to this:
https://gist.github.com/Willshaw/6621360

If the 2 strings matched, I knew all controllers where loaded and I could run my app.